# Resolution failed with error: No public constructor is available for type IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, httpcontext, hangfire-unity

I recently upgraded my app to .net core 6 and now I am getting this error when trying to get a service using this code:

```
IUnityContainer container = HangfireUnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
var authService = container.Resolve<IAuthService>();
```

I read some other posts that mentioned adding HttpContextAccessor in my ConfigureServices() method but none of the ways ive tried fixed the error.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Another person mentioned adding the line in my Program.cs but still getting the error.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

If I add RegisterType<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>() to RegisterTypes() in my HangFireUnityConfig class the error goes away but throws a new error later on so Im not sure if thats the right fix.

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
            // register hangfire dependencies
            container.RegisterType<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()
}
```

AuthService.cs

```
using MyApp.Entities.DTOs;

namespace MyApp.Service.Auth
{
    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {
        private UserDto currentUser = null;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
        public AuthService(IHttpContextAccessor ctx)
        {
            _context = ctx;
            currentUser = parseClaimsUser();
        }

        public bool isInRole(string role, List<string> roleList)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public UserDto parseClaimsUser()
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal currentClaim = _context.HttpContext.User;
            UserDto parsedUser = new UserDto();
            bool isAdmin = false;

            if (currentClaim == null || !currentClaim.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return parsedUser;
            }
            //return user id from token properties
            parsedUser.userID = currentClaim.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            // retrieve groups from token properties --- this is only retrieved upon login. Users will have to log out and log back in to see any changes in groups
            var currentGroupsIDs = currentClaim.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role) ?
                                                     currentClaim.Claims.Where(t => t.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(y => int.Parse(y.Value)).ToList<int>()
                                                     : new List<int>();                                    

            var adminString = currentClaim.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision)
                .Select(v => v.Value)
                .SingleOrDefault<string>();

            adminString = adminString == null ? "False" : adminString;

            isAdmin = bool.Parse(adminString);

            //parsedUser.userGrp = currentGroups;
            parsedUser.userGrpIDs = currentGroupsIDs;
            parsedUser.isAuthenticated = currentClaim.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            parsedUser.displayName = currentClaim.Identity.Name;
            parsedUser.email = currentClaim.Claims.Where(w => w.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(v => v.Value).SingleOrDefault<string>();
            //parsedUser.currentToken = tokenExtract;
            parsedUser.isAdmin = isAdmin;
            var isUS = currentClaim.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "us_citizen").Select(v => v.Value).SingleOrDefault<string>();
            if (isUS != null)
            {
                parsedUser.isUSCitizenAndJPLEmployee = bool.Parse(isUS);
            }

            return parsedUser;
        }

        public void initUser()
        {
            currentUser = parseClaimsUser();
        }

        public UserDto getCurrentUser(bool includeToken = false)
        {
            if (currentUser == null || currentUser.userID == null)
            {
                currentUser = parseClaimsUser();
            }

            if (!includeToken)
            {
                currentUser.currentToken = null;
            }

            return currentUser;
        }

        public bool userIsAdmin()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need the line `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`. The rest is garbage

Comment: Can you share the implementation of IAuthService?

Comment: @CKK services.AddHttpContextAccessor() is what I had before upgrading but not it throws that error

Comment: @sa-es-ir I added my IAuthService but I dont think thats the problem

Comment: No, I meant the class that implements the IAuthService!

Comment: @sa-es-ir ok i added the code for my AuthService which implements IAuthService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the error I was getting with my last implementation. The error was with not being able to cast my dbContext to type IObjectContextAdapter.

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, long>> GetKeys(EntityEntry entry)
{
    var keys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
    var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);

    if (objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues != null)
    {
        keys.AddRange(objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, long>(key.Key, Convert.ToInt64(key.Value))));
    }

    return keys;
}
```

I refactored the code to look like this and got no errors.

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, long>> GetKeys(EntityEntry entry)
        {
           //this gets an array of the key names
            var keyNames = entry.Metadata.FindPrimaryKey()
              .Properties
              .Select(p => p.Name)
              .ToArray();

            var keys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
            
            if (keyNames != null)
            {
                //creates the KeyValuePairs
                keys.AddRange(keyNames.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string, long>(key, Convert.ToInt64(entry.Property(key).CurrentValue))));

            }

            return keys;
        }
```